# When I plug a USB camera in I get strange characters displaying on the screen

Tags: raspbian, usb, camera, linux, webcam

I have a raspberry pi B+ running the latest Jessie image (Linux raspberrypi 4.9.22+ ). I have a monitor, usb keyboard and usb mouse plugged into it. I also have a wired ethernet plugged in. No other usb devices.

When I plug a USB camera in (Microsoft VX-1000) I start to get the character ^@ printed to my screen over and over. It just keeps going. The interval between the character being printed isn't the same. It is fairly random but I can get a load of 20 characters in a few seconds, then a second or so break then 10 more and so on.

If I unplug the camera the problem goes away. This was find up until last week and I don't believe I have made any system changes to cause it.

Here is the kern.log file from boot

```
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.9.22+ (dc4@dc4-XPS13-9333) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611) ) #987 Fri Apr 14 23:13:48 BST 2017
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] CPU: ARMv6-compatible processor [410fb767] revision 7 (ARMv7), cr=00c5387d
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT nonaliasing instruction cache
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] OF: fdt:Machine model: Raspberry Pi Model B Plus Rev 1.2
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] cma: Reserved 8 MiB at 0x17400000
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writeback
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 98304
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat c0914814, node_mem_map d7c8bf00
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000]   Normal zone: 864 pages used for memmap
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000]   Normal zone: 98304 pages, LIFO batch:31
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s0 r0 d32768 u32768 alloc=1*32768
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 97440
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Kernel command line: bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1680 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=1050 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 vc_mem.mem_base=0x1ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x20000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=PA RTUUID=bd13bc79-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Memory: 370988K/393216K available (5941K kernel code, 489K rwdata, 1948K rodata, 404K init, 734K bss, 14036K reserved, 8192K cma-reserved)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000]     vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000]     fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000]     vmalloc : 0xd8800000 - 0xff800000   ( 624 MB)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000]     lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xd8000000   ( 384 MB)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000]     modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xc0000000   (  16 MB)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000]       .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc05d593c   (5943 kB)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000]       .init : 0xc083f000 - 0xc08a4000   ( 404 kB)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000]       .data : 0xc08a4000 - 0xc091e6c8   ( 490 kB)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000]        .bss : 0xc091e6c8 - 0xc09d5ec8   ( 734 kB)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=32, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] NR_IRQS:16 nr_irqs:16 16
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000029] sched_clock: 32 bits at 1000kHz, resolution 1000ns, wraps every 2147483647500ns
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000072] clocksource: timer: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 1911260446275 ns
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000170] bcm2835: system timer (irq = 27)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000638] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.001371] console [tty1] enabled
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.001427] Calibrating delay loop... 697.95 BogoMIPS (lpj=3489792)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.060340] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.060792] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.060862] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.061961] Disabling cpuset control group subsystem
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.062231] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.062339] ftrace: allocating 21708 entries in 64 pages
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.178062] Setting up static identity map for 0x8200 - 0x8238
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.180116] devtmpfs: initialized
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.188704] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 1 part 20 variant b rev 5
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.189215] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.189314] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: -1, 3072 bytes)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.190631] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.192137] NET: Registered protocol family 16
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.194555] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.204076] hw-breakpoint: found 6 breakpoint and 1 watchpoint registers.
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.204169] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 4 bytes.
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.204312] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.207092] bcm2835-mbox 2000b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.254697] bcm2835-dma 20007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager at d880d000, dmachans=0x1
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.257395] SCSI subsystem initialized
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.257720] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.257892] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.258225] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.268136] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2017-04-04 18:50
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.270052] clocksource: Switched to clocksource timer
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.327144] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.327340] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.327677] FS-Cache: Loaded
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.328075] CacheFiles: Loaded
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.347622] NET: Registered protocol family 2
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.349045] TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.349200] TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.349330] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.349460] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.349527] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.349877] NET: Registered protocol family 1
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.350776] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.350855] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.350894] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.350929] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.352028] hw perfevents: enabled with armv6_1176 PMU driver, 3 counters available
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.354459] workingset: timestamp_bits=14 max_order=17 bucket_order=3
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.374225] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.376005] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.376116] Key type id_resolver registered
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.376158] Key type id_legacy registered
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.380702] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 251)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.381167] io scheduler noop registered
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.381232] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.381734] io scheduler cfq registered
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.387572] BCM2708FB: allocated DMA memory 57500000
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.387702] BCM2708FB: allocated DMA channel 0 @ d880d000
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.432668] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 210x65
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.468954] bcm2835-rng 20104000.rng: hwrng registered
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.469378] vc-cma: Videocore CMA driver
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.469555] vc-cma: vc_cma_base      = 0x00000000
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.469747] vc-cma: vc_cma_size      = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.469951] vc-cma: vc_cma_initial   = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.470771] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x1ec00000 mem_size:0x20000000(512 MiB)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.499161] brd: module loaded
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.513200] loop: module loaded
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.513371] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.514562] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.514837] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.741454] Core Release: 2.80a
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.741632] Setting default values for core params
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.741862] Finished setting default values for core params
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.942519] Using Buffer DMA mode
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.942696] Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.942917] Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.943126] OTG VER PARAM: 0, OTG VER FLAG: 0
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.943383] Dedicated Tx FIFOs mode
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.944280] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_init:1053: FIQ DMA bounce buffers: virt = 0xd7514000 dma = 0x57514000 len=9024
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.944678] FIQ FSM acceleration enabled for :
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.944678] Non-periodic Split Transactions
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.944678] Periodic Split Transactions
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.944678] High-Speed Isochronous Endpoints
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.944678] Interrupt/Control Split Transaction hack enabled
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.945432] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.945559] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:459: FIQ on core 0 at 0xc0450398
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.945797] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:460: FIQ ASM at 0xc0450674 length 36
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.946045] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:486: MPHI regs_base at 0xd88a5000
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.946354] dwc_otg 20980000.usb: DWC OTG Controller
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.946607] dwc_otg 20980000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.955842] dwc_otg 20980000.usb: irq 56, io mem 0x00000000
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.964816] Init: Port Power? op_state=1
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.973696] Init: Power Port (0)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.982895] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.992006] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.000951] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.009813] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.9.22+ dwc_otg_hcd
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.018622] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 20980000.usb
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.028942] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.037948] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.047757] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.047770] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.047775] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.047799] Module dwc_common_port init
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.048384] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.058010] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.068826] bcm2835-wdt 20100000.watchdog: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.078632] bcm2835-cpufreq: min=700000 max=700000
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.088466] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.097530] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.107017] sdhost-bcm2835 20202000.sdhost: could not get clk, deferring probe
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.116465] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.126397] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.135703] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.145103] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.154200] usbhid: USB HID core driver
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.164805] vchiq: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = 0xd7580000, is_master = 0
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.177079] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.187389] NET: Registered protocol family 17
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.197066] Key type dns_resolver registered
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.208192] registered taskstats version 1
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.217866] vc-sm: Videocore shared memory driver
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.227066] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.237310] [vc_sm_connected_init]: end - returning 0
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.254537] 20201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x20201000 (irq = 81, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.266640] sdhost: log_buf @ d7513000 (57513000)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.297359] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.378786] random: fast init done
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.390140] mmc0: sdhost-bcm2835 loaded - DMA enabled (>1)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.399775] of_cfs_init
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.429717] of_cfs_init: OK
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.440699] Waiting for root device PARTUUID=bd13bc79-02...
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.497988] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.507748] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.517858] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.588035] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 59b4
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.599146] mmcblk0: mmc0:59b4 00000 7.35 GiB
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.611712]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.703845] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.713695] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): write access will be enabled during recovery
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.780826] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9514
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.790695] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.805790] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    1.818026] hub 1-1:1.0: 5 ports detected
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    2.118451] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): recovery complete
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    2.137363] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    2.147100] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:2.
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    2.156705] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    2.192435] devtmpfs: mounted
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    2.203552] Freeing unused kernel memory: 404K (c083f000 - c08a4000)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    2.213276] This architecture does not have kernel memory protection.
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    2.290761] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    2.300811] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    2.315145] smsc95xx v1.0.5
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    2.420571] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-20980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:a4:9a:96
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    2.530293] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    2.673299] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=00f7
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    2.673315] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    2.673325] usb 1-1.2: Product: USB camera
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    2.770188] usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    2.891418] NET: Registered protocol family 10
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    2.963977] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=413c, idProduct=2112
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    2.974700] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    2.985205] usb 1-1.3: Product: Dell USB Wired Multimedia Keyboard
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    2.995731] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: DELL
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.025443] input: DELL Dell USB Wired Multimedia Keyboard as /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:413C:2112.0001/input/input0
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.101503] hid-generic 0003:413C:2112.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [DELL Dell USB Wired Multimedia Keyboard] on usb-20980000.usb-1.3/input0
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.155354] input: DELL Dell USB Wired Multimedia Keyboard as /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.1/0003:413C:2112.0002/input/input1
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.250900] hid-generic 0003:413C:2112.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [DELL Dell USB Wired Multimedia Keyboard] on usb-20980000.usb-1.3/input1
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    4.997290] fuse init (API version 7.26)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    5.035868] i2c /dev entries driver
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    8.707758] gpiomem-bcm2835 20200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0x20200000
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    9.117898] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [   10.503498] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [   11.121121] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [   11.222005] gspca_main: v2.14.0 registered
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [   11.252664] gspca_main: sonixj-2.14.0 probing 045e:00f7
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [   11.500837] input: sonixj as /devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/input/input2
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [   11.595744] usbcore: registered new interface driver sonixj
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [   12.534851] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
Apr 21 16:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [   14.775507] random: crng init done
Apr 21 16:21:16 raspberrypi kernel: [   18.738606] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-1 extents:5 across:225280k SSFS
Apr 21 16:21:19 raspberrypi kernel: [   21.984288] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
Apr 21 16:21:20 raspberrypi kernel: [   23.570295] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x41E1
Apr 21 16:21:33 raspberrypi kernel: [   36.427096] sonixj 1-1.2:1.0: URB error -32, resubmitting
Apr 21 16:21:33 raspberrypi kernel: [   36.491094] sonixj 1-1.2:1.0: URB error -32, resubmitting
Apr 21 16:21:33 raspberrypi kernel: [   36.555083] sonixj 1-1.2:1.0: URB error -32, resubmitting
Apr 21 16:21:33 raspberrypi kernel: [   36.612641] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
```

Unfortunately, I dont have another webcam to try.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial end error I tracked it down to the /boot/config.txt setup.
I wanted to use the serial line for something else. As the PI uses the serial line for debugging output you have to disable it via configuration settings. One of the commands to do this is:

> dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt

This is only needed for the PI3 but is said to not affect other PI's so I put it anyway. Turns out it seemed to cause an issue. Changing it to

> dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt

Seemed to resolve it

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.